# Plan command in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any `plan` command in Kubernetes? With `terraform plan` command we know which resources will be added and removed before applying changes. Is there any similar in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubectl accepts a flag `--dry-run=client|server` which is similar. Using `--dry-run` flag alone is deprecated in v1.18 and generates a warning (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/14/apiserver-dry-run-and-kubectl-diff/)

For example: `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --dry-run=client`

If client strategy, only prints the object that would be sent, without sending it. If server strategy, submit a server-side request without persisting the resource.

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands

Answer (score 2):

You can use the --dry-run flag to preview the object that would be sent to your cluster, without really submitting it. Refer https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/14/apiserver-dry-run-and-kubectl-diff/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#dry-run